# Eclipse-plugin-dev: How to get current bundle version?

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-plugin, manifest.mf

In Eclipse plugin development: How to get current bundle version?

It is just in Manifest.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Nodeclipse
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.nodeclipse.ui;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.6.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: org.nodeclipse.ui.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
```

However Java has method only to look at Bundle Implementation version
`getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a plug-in you can use:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("org.nodeeclipse.ui");
Version version = bundle.getVersion();
```

`Version` has `getMajor`, `getMinor`, `getMicro`, `getQualifier` methods.

`Platform` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform`

Comment: I think this is too brittle. If the bundle name changes, this code will no longer work.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian If you want the bundle you are currently running in then, yes, use FrameworkUtil.getBundle. However when you are doing things like processing extension point definitions all you have is the plugin id so in that case use this method.

Answer (score 25):

In a more OSGi way, not having to know your name, and official standard way:

```
 Version version = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()).getVersion();
```

Notice that the bundle version you get is from the bundle from which the this was loaded. So do not put this in a convenience library in another bundle!